# Running Two Event Loops In One File

Tags: python, flask, discord, uvicorn, quart

I have created a web app, that has two event loops. One for the actual web app(which I made using the Quart microframework), and one for the Discord bot.

Because I'm running two event loops, I have made a thread for the Discord bot.

The app works fine when I run it using the Python interperator, but doesn't work when I run the Quart app with Uvicorn.

```py
# Application.py
 
import os
import sys
import quart
from quart_discord import DiscordOAuth2Session
from Database import InformationLogManager
from Bot import Main
import threading
import asyncio
import typelog
 
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
 
GUILD_ID = 1208428835960520734
ROLE_ID = 1208433206215315558
 
Application = quart.Quart('888KingBotDashboard')
InformationLogManager = InformationLogManager.InformationLogManager() # this is a database
Logger = typelog.get_logger(__name__)
 
Application.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "thebigchickens"
Application.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_ID"] = '1208431980954525746'
Application.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET"] = 'ghvM9A2128vrz9vEzXrvOxp1ff28FIEC'
Application.config["DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI"] = "http://localhost:8080/callback"
 
DiscordOAuth2Session = DiscordOAuth2Session(Application)
 
@Application.before_serving
async def BeforeFirstRequest():
    BotThread = threading.Thread(target=Main.RunBot) # Runs the Discord bot.
    BotThread.start()
 
@Application.route('/')
async def index():
    return await quart.render_template('index.html')
 
@Application.route('/login')
async def Login():
    return await DiscordOAuth2Session.create_session()
 
@Application.route('/callback')
async def callback():
    try:
        await DiscordOAuth2Session.callback()
    except Exception:
        return quart.redirect(quart.url_for("login"))
 
    User = await DiscordOAuth2Session.fetch_user()
    print(User)
    return await quart.render_template('logged_in_success.html', User = User)
 
@Application.route('/dashboard')
async def dashboard():
    for Guild in await DiscordOAuth2Session.fetch_guilds():
        if Guild.id == GUILD_ID:
            User = await DiscordOAuth2Session.fetch_user()
            if await Main.CheckForRole(GuildId = GUILD_ID, RoleId = ROLE_ID, UserId = User.id):
                InformationLogManager.LogInformation(
                    DiscordUserId = User.id,
                    IPAddress = quart.request.remote_addr,
                    Email = User.email
                )
                return await quart.render_template("dashboard.html", User = User)
            else:
                break
        else:
            continue
    return await quart.render_template("access_denied.html"), 401
```

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1 (RunBot):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 1116, in run
Exception in callback Future.set_result(True)
handle: <TimerHandle when=527018.265 Future.set_result(True)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: invalid state
    loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 319, in run_forever
INFO:     ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
    assert self._self_reading_future is None
AssertionError
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 133, in _cleanup_loop
    _cancel_tasks(loop)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 115, in _cancel_tasks
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True))
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 617, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 577, in _check_running
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 79, in serve
    await self.startup(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 161, in startup
    server = await loop.create_server(
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1459, in create_server
    infos = await tasks.gather(*fs)
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 418, in main
    run(
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 587, in run
    server.run()
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 62, in run
    Client.run("MTIwODQzMTk4MDk1NDUyNTc0Ng.GJL1Ys.WJk760ouaguhQ818OJMu8z9GvKDOzFAA0pBxuk")
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 1122, in run
    _cleanup_loop(loop)
  File "C:\Users\junej\dev\888BotRestructure\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 137, in _cleanup_loop
    loop.close()
  File "C:\Users\junej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 676, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, I  solved the issue.

Essentially what I did was use `asyncio.get_event_loop`, to get the current event loop that was being spawned by the Uvicorn server. This returned a `ProactorEventLoop` object, which I then used its `create_task` method to run the bot.

This is the update I made:

```py
ApplicationEventLoop: asyncio.windows_events.ProactorEventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop() 
ApplicationEventLoop.create_task(Main.RunBot())
```